# MVVMCross System.AggregateException 6.4 Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am in the process of updating from MVVMCross 5.7 to 6.4.

I have followed the StarWars example, but I'm running in an error while trying to start the android app. I always get a System.AggregateException on base.OnCreate(bundle);

This is my base project App and Custom AppStart

```
  public class App : MvxApplication
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes this instance.
        /// </summary>
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            CreatableTypes()
                .EndingWith("Service")
                .AsInterfaces()
                .RegisterAsLazySingleton();



            RegisterCustomAppStart<AppStart>();
        }
    }
```

```
public class AppStart : MvxAppStart
    {
        public AppStart(IMvxApplication app, IMvxNavigationService mvxNavigationService)
            : base(app, mvxNavigationService)
        {
        }

        protected override Task NavigateToFirstViewModel(object hint = null)
        {
            var token = Settings.Token;
            var skipIntro = Settings.SkipIntro;


            if (!skipIntro)
            {
                return NavigationService.Navigate<IntroViewModel>();

            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                return NavigationService.Navigate<MainViewModel>();
            }
            else
            {
                return NavigationService.Navigate<WelcomeViewModel>();

            }
        }
```

And this is my SplashScreen, Setup and MainApplication in the android project.

```
  [MvxActivityPresentation]
    [Activity(
        MainLauncher = true,
        Label = "@string/applicationName",
        Icon = "@drawable/icon_main",
        NoHistory = true,
        ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public class SplashScreenView : MvxSplashScreenActivity
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SplashScreenView"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public SplashScreenView() : base(Resource.Layout.screen_splash)
        {
        }


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            ImageView img = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.loadingImage);

            if (img != null)
            {
                img.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Animation.loading_animation);

                // Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
                AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)img.Background;

                // Start the animation (looped playback by default).
                frameAnimation.Start();
            }
        }
    }
```

```
 public class Setup : MvxAppCompatSetup<App>
    {
        private readonly object _applicationContext;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Setup"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="applicationContext">The application context.</param>

        protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> AndroidViewAssemblies => new List<Assembly>(base.AndroidViewAssemblies)
        {
            typeof(NavigationView).Assembly,
            typeof(CoordinatorLayout).Assembly,
            typeof(FloatingActionButton).Assembly,
            typeof(Toolbar).Assembly,
            typeof(DrawerLayout).Assembly,
            typeof(ViewPager).Assembly,
            typeof(MvxSwipeRefreshLayout).Assembly,
        };


        protected override IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()
        {
            return new MvxAppCompatViewPresenter(AndroidViewAssemblies);
        }

        protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
        {

            MvxAppCompatSetupHelper.FillTargetFactories(registry);
            base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
        }

    }
```

```
 [Application]
    public class MainApplication : MvxAppCompatApplication<Setup, App>
    {

        public MainApplication()
        {
        }

        public MainApplication(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
            : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {
        }

    }
```

Whenever the application navigates to InfoViewModel it crashes with System.AggregateException:  error.

I am also including the InfoView file for reference.

```
   [MvxActivityPresentation]
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Intro", Label = "", NoHistory = true)]
    public class IntroView : MvxAppCompatActivity<IntroViewModel>
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            this.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.screen_intro);

            var video = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.introVideoView);

            video.Touch += delegate(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs args) { ViewModel.SkipCommand.Execute(null); };
            video.Completion += delegate(object sender, EventArgs args) { ViewModel.SkipCommand.Execute(null); };

            var uri = Uri.Parse("android.resource://" + PackageName + "/" + Resource.Drawable.video_intro);
            video.SetVideoURI(uri);
            video.Start();
        }
    }
```

I am following exactly what happens in the StarWars example, however I couldn't manage to get it to run. Any suggestions or anything obvious that I still havent managed to see?

Kind regards,

EDIT:
Adding part of the stackTrace

```
2019-09-30 15:21:40 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: Create App
2019-09-30 15:21:40 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: NavigationService
09-30 15:21:40.514 I/mono-stdout(12097): 2019-09-30 15:21:40 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: NavigationService
09-30 15:21:40.569 I/mono-stdout(12097): 2019-09-30 15:21:40 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: Load navigation routes
2019-09-30 15:21:40 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: Load navigation routes
2019-09-30 15:21:40 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: App start
09-30 15:21:40.670 I/mono-stdout(12097): 2019-09-30 15:21:40 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: App start
09-30 15:21:40.687 I/mono-stdout(12097): 2019-09-30 15:21:40 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: Application Initialize - On background thread
2019-09-30 15:21:40 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: Application Initialize - On background thread
09-30 15:21:40.999 D/OpenGLRenderer(12097): Skia GL Pipeline
2019-09-30 15:21:41 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: ViewModelTypeFinder start
09-30 15:21:41.402 I/mono-stdout(12097): 2019-09-30 15:21:41 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: ViewModelTypeFinder start
09-30 15:21:41.680 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref netstandard[0xe7d85c00] -> System[0xed847880]: 12
09-30 15:21:41.712 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref netstandard[0xe7d85c00] -> System.Core[0xe63a5e00]: 6
09-30 15:21:41.780 D/Mono    (12097): Image addref System.Net.Http[0xe7d86800] -> System.Net.Http.dll[0xc8c64e00]: 2
09-30 15:21:41.781 D/Mono    (12097): Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Net.Http' (System.Net.Http.dll)
09-30 15:21:41.787 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly System.Net.Http[0xe7d86800] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
09-30 15:21:41.851 I/Choreographer(12097): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-30 15:21:41.913 D/Mono    (12097): AOT: image 'System.Net.Http.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.talkingmedicines.medsmart-353GoKCmCuAZwDW2_PDbJA==/lib/x86/libaot-System.Net.Http.dll.so" not found
09-30 15:21:41.914 D/Mono    (12097): AOT: image '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-x86-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Net.Http.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.talkingmedicines.medsmart-353GoKCmCuAZwDW2_PDbJA==/lib/x86/libaot-System.Net.Http.dll.so" not found
09-30 15:21:41.924 D/Mono    (12097): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Net.Http.dll.config'.
09-30 15:21:41.924 D/Mono    (12097): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-x86-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http.config'.
09-30 15:21:41.925 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref netstandard[0xe7d85c00] -> System.Net.Http[0xe7d86800]: 2
09-30 15:21:41.925 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref System.Net.Http[0xe7d86800] -> mscorlib[0xed8647c0]: 95
09-30 15:21:41.930 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref MedSmart.App[0xe5f095a0] -> Newtonsoft.Json[0xe5f0a080]: 3
Loaded assembly: System.Net.Http.dll [External]
2019-09-30 15:21:42 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: ViewsContainer start
09-30 15:21:42.009 I/mono-stdout(12097): 2019-09-30 15:21:42 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: ViewsContainer start
2019-09-30 15:21:42 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: Lookup Dictionary start09-30 15:21:42.053 I/mono-stdout(12097): 2019-09-30 15:21:42 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: Lookup Dictionary start

09-30 15:21:42.364 D/        (12097): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd1e5bb40, tid 12149
09-30 15:21:42.565 I/ConfigStore(12097): android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
09-30 15:21:42.568 I/ConfigStore(12097): android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
09-30 15:21:42.568 I/OpenGLRenderer(12097): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-30 15:21:42.569 D/OpenGLRenderer(12097): Swap behavior 1
09-30 15:21:42.580 W/OpenGLRenderer(12097): Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
09-30 15:21:42.581 D/OpenGLRenderer(12097): Swap behavior 0
09-30 15:21:42.758 D/EGL_emulation(12097): eglCreateContext: 0xe7d86aa0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
09-30 15:21:42.769 D/Mono    (12097): Image addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0xe7d86fe0] -> System.Runtime.Serialization.dll[0xc8c65d00]: 2
09-30 15:21:42.769 D/Mono    (12097): Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization' (System.Runtime.Serialization.dll)
09-30 15:21:42.769 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly System.Runtime.Serialization[0xe7d86fe0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
09-30 15:21:42.785 D/EGL_emulation(12097): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe7d86aa0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc8b7eda0)
09-30 15:21:42.810 D/Mono    (12097): AOT: image 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.talkingmedicines.medsmart-353GoKCmCuAZwDW2_PDbJA==/lib/x86/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found
09-30 15:21:42.811 D/Mono    (12097): AOT: image '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-x86-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.talkingmedicines.medsmart-353GoKCmCuAZwDW2_PDbJA==/lib/x86/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found
09-30 15:21:42.811 D/Mono    (12097): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.config'.
09-30 15:21:42.811 D/Mono    (12097): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-x86-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Runtime.Serialization/System.Runtime.Serialization.config'.
09-30 15:21:42.811 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0xe63a5c20] -> System.Runtime.Serialization[0xe7d86fe0]: 2
09-30 15:21:42.819 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0xe7d86fe0] -> mscorlib[0xed8647c0]: 96
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
09-30 15:21:43.977 D/EGL_emulation(12097): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe7d86aa0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc8b7eda0)
09-30 15:21:44.888 I/OpenGLRenderer(12097): Davey! duration=1862ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=12658796993658, Vsync=12659013660316, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=12659032900880, AnimationStart=12659033029580, PerformTraversalsStart=12659040149880, DrawStart=12659527054380, SyncQueued=12659753000480, SyncStart=12659888112480, IssueDrawCommandsStart=12659902310880, SwapBuffers=12660452490380, FrameCompleted=12660794845380, DequeueBufferDuration=1504000, QueueBufferDuration=78423000, 
09-30 15:21:45.194 I/mono-stdout(12097): 2019-09-30 15:21:45 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Logging.MvxLog) No view model association found for candidate view BaseActivity
2019-09-30 15:21:45 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Logging.MvxLog) No view model association found for candidate view BaseActivity
09-30 15:21:46.308 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Facebook.Common.Android[0xe63a45a0] -> Xamarin.Facebook.Core.Android[0xe63a4660]: 3
09-30 15:21:46.751 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref MedSmart.App.Droid[0xed864c40] -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement[0xe63a5260]: 2
09-30 15:21:46.817 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base[0xe63a51a0] -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement[0xe63a5260]: 3
2019-09-30 15:21:46 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: Views start09-30 15:21:46.996 I/mono-stdout(12097): 2019-09-30 15:21:46 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: Views start

2019-09-30 15:21:47 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: CommandCollectionBuilder start
09-30 15:21:47.296 I/mono-stdout(12097): 2019-09-30 15:21:47 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: CommandCollectionBuilder start
2019-09-30 15:21:47 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: NavigationSerializer start
09-30 15:21:47.379 I/mono-stdout(12097): 2019-09-30 15:21:47 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: NavigationSerializer start
2019-09-30 15:21:47 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: InpcInterception start
2019-09-30 15:21:47 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: InpcInterception start09-30 15:21:47.462 I/mono-stdout(12097): 2019-09-30 15:21:47 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: InpcInterception start

09-30 15:21:47.471 I/mono-stdout(12097): 2019-09-30 15:21:47 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: InpcInterception start
09-30 15:21:47.568 I/mono-stdout(12097): 2019-09-30 15:21:47 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: LastChance start
2019-09-30 15:21:47 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: LastChance start
09-30 15:21:49.160 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref MedSmart.App.Droid[0xed864c40] -> ModernHttpClient[0xe5f09840]: 2
09-30 15:21:49.160 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref ModernHttpClient[0xe5f09840] -> mscorlib[0xed8647c0]: 97
09-30 15:21:49.219 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref MedSmart.App.Droid[0xed864c40] -> MvvmCross.Droid.Support.Core.Utils[0xe5f09a80]: 2
09-30 15:21:49.231 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref MedSmart.App.Droid[0xed864c40] -> MvvmCross.Droid.Support.Design[0xe5f09b40]: 2
09-30 15:21:49.400 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref MedSmart.App.Droid[0xed864c40] -> MvvmCross.Droid.Support.Fragment[0xe5f09c00]: 2
09-30 15:21:49.592 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref MedSmart.App.Droid[0xed864c40] -> MvvmCross.Plugin.Visibility[0xe5f09f00]: 2
09-30 15:21:49.593 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref MedSmart.App.Droid[0xed864c40] -> MvvmCross.Plugin.WebBrowser[0xe5f09fc0]: 2
09-30 15:21:50.003 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref ModernHttpClient[0xe5f09840] -> Mono.Android[0xe63a5c20]: 87
09-30 15:21:50.341 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref MvvmCross.Droid.Support.Core.Utils[0xe5f09a80] -> Mono.Android[0xe63a5c20]: 88
09-30 15:21:54.391 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0xe63a5c20] -> System.Net.Http[0xe7d86800]: 3
09-30 15:21:54.489 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0xe63a5c20] -> System[0xed847880]: 13
09-30 15:21:56.116 I/mono-stdout(12097): 2019-09-30 15:21:56 [WARN]  (MvvmCross.Logging.MvxLog) ReflectionTypeLoadException masked during loading of MvvmCross, Version=6.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null - error ReflectionTypeLoadException: Exception of type 'System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException' was thrown.
2019-09-30 15:21:56 [WARN]  (MvvmCross.Logging.MvxLog) ReflectionTypeLoadException masked during loading of MvvmCross, Version=6.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null - error ReflectionTypeLoadException: Exception of type 'System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException' was thrown.
      at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes(System.Reflection.Assembly,bool)
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 09-30 15:21:56.119 I/mono-stdout(12097):    at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes(System.Reflection.Assembly,bool)

  at System.Reflection.Assembly+<get_DefinedTypes>d__140.MoveNext () [0x0001e] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[TSource,TResult].MoveNext () [0x00059] in <715c2ff6913942e6aa8535593b3ef35a>:0 
  at MvvmCross.IoC.MvxTypeCache`1[TType].AddAssembly (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly) [0x000c6] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\IoC\MvxTypeCache.cs:31 09-30 15:21:56.119 I/mono-stdout(12097):   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 

09-30 15:21:56.123 I/mono-stdout(12097):   at System.Reflection.Assembly+<get_DefinedTypes>d__140.MoveNext () [0x0001e] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
09-30 15:21:56.124 I/mono-stdout(12097):   at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[TSource,TResult].MoveNext () [0x00059] in <715c2ff6913942e6aa8535593b3ef35a>:0 
09-30 15:21:56.125 I/mono-stdout(12097):   at MvvmCross.IoC.MvxTypeCache`1[TType].AddAssembly (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly) [0x000c6] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\IoC\MvxTypeCache.cs:31 
09-30 15:21:56.201 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat[0xe5f0bfa0] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomView[0xe5f0b520]: 2
09-30 15:21:56.250 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Support.DrawerLayout[0xe5f0b760] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat[0xe5f0b0a0]: 7
09-30 15:21:56.252 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Support.DrawerLayout[0xe5f0b760] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomView[0xe5f0b520]: 3
09-30 15:21:56.289 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Support.Design[0xe5f0b5e0] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.CoordinaterLayout[0xe5f0b160]: 4
09-30 15:21:56.304 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Support.Design[0xe5f0b5e0] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView[0xe63a4060]: 2
09-30 15:21:56.307 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Support.Design[0xe5f0b5e0] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomView[0xe5f0b520]: 4
09-30 15:21:56.342 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Support.Design[0xe5f0b5e0] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView[0xe63a4120]: 2
09-30 15:21:56.358 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView[0xe63a4120] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat[0xe5f0b0a0]: 8
09-30 15:21:56.358 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Support.Design[0xe5f0b5e0] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition[0xe5f0be20]: 2
09-30 15:21:56.369 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Support.Design[0xe5f0b5e0] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.ViewPager[0xe63a4360]: 5
09-30 15:21:56.391 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Support.CoordinaterLayout[0xe5f0b160] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomView[0xe5f0b520]: 5
09-30 15:21:56.394 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Support.ViewPager[0xe63a4360] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat[0xe5f0b0a0]: 9
09-30 15:21:56.404 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Support.ViewPager[0xe63a4360] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomView[0xe5f0b520]: 6
09-30 15:21:57.931 D/Mono    (12097): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
09-30 15:21:57.932 D/Mono    (12097): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_field_id'.
09-30 15:21:57.932 D/Mono    (12097): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_field_id'.
09-30 15:21:57.932 D/Mono    (12097): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_field_id'.
09-30 15:21:57.959 D/Mono    (12097): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
09-30 15:21:57.959 D/Mono    (12097): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_object_field'.
09-30 15:21:57.959 D/Mono    (12097): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_object_field'.
09-30 15:21:57.959 D/Mono    (12097): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_object_field'.
2019-09-30 15:21:59 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Logging.MvxLog) AppStart: Application Startup - On UI thread09-30 15:21:59.155 I/mono-stdout(12097): 2019-09-30 15:21:59 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Logging.MvxLog) AppStart: Application Startup - On UI thread

09-30 15:21:59.252 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref MedSmart.App[0xe5f095a0] -> Plugin.Settings.Abstractions[0xe5f0a4a0]: 2
09-30 15:21:59.327 D/Mono    (12097): Unloading image System.Runtime.dll [0xc8b9ba00].
09-30 15:21:59.332 D/Mono    (12097): Image addref System.Runtime[0xc8bfe380] -> System.Runtime.dll[0xc9a2cd00]: 6
09-30 15:21:59.332 D/Mono    (12097): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Runtime.dll.config'.
09-30 15:21:59.332 D/Mono    (12097): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-x86-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.config'.
09-30 15:21:59.332 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Plugin.Settings.Abstractions[0xe5f0a4a0] -> System.Runtime[0xe7d85c60]: 4
09-30 15:21:59.333 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref MedSmart.App[0xe5f095a0] -> Plugin.Settings[0xe5f0a560]: 2
09-30 15:21:59.340 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Plugin.Settings[0xe5f0a560] -> mscorlib[0xed8647c0]: 98
09-30 15:21:59.340 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Plugin.Settings[0xe5f0a560] -> Plugin.Settings.Abstractions[0xe5f0a4a0]: 3
09-30 15:21:59.413 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Plugin.Settings[0xe5f0a560] -> Mono.Android[0xe63a5c20]: 89
09-30 15:21:59.672 D/Mono    (12097): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
09-30 15:21:59.673 D/Mono    (12097): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method_a'.
09-30 15:21:59.673 D/Mono    (12097): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method_a'.
09-30 15:21:59.673 D/Mono    (12097): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method_a'.
09-30 15:22:00.494 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat[0xe5f09cc0] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment[0xe5f0b820]: 5
09-30 15:22:00.626 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat[0xe5f09cc0] -> System.Core[0xe63a5e00]: 7
09-30 15:22:02.033 I/icines.medsmar(12097): Background concurrent copying GC freed 10897(1004KB) AllocSpace objects, 10(264KB) LOS objects, 51% free, 1452KB/2MB, paused 19.968ms total 232.701ms
09-30 15:22:02.348 W/icines.medsmar(12097): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md5716162e2cd7f7ce01364d7c5d961f40b.MvxAppCompatActivity_1
09-30 15:22:04.221 I/Choreographer(12097): Skipped 328 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-30 15:22:04.397 I/OpenGLRenderer(12097): Davey! duration=5644ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=12674653852755, Vsync=12680120519203, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=12680128791380, AnimationStart=12680138049980, PerformTraversalsStart=12680183108580, DrawStart=12680187429780, SyncQueued=12680211639680, SyncStart=12680212716680, IssueDrawCommandsStart=12680217558180, SwapBuffers=12680292113880, FrameCompleted=12680299691980, DequeueBufferDuration=88000, QueueBufferDuration=510000, 
09-30 15:22:04.638 W/ActivityThread(12097): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@7a003e6
09-30 15:22:06.703 D/Mono    (12097): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
09-30 15:22:06.703 D/Mono    (12097): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_int_field'.
09-30 15:22:06.703 D/Mono    (12097): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_int_field'.
09-30 15:22:06.703 D/Mono    (12097): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_int_field'.
09-30 15:22:07.682 D/Mono    (12097): Image addref Mono.Android.Export[0xc8bfd960] -> Mono.Android.Export.dll[0xc8b9c400]: 2
09-30 15:22:07.694 D/Mono    (12097): Prepared to set up assembly 'Mono.Android.Export' (Mono.Android.Export.dll)
09-30 15:22:07.694 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Mono.Android.Export[0xc8bfd960] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
09-30 15:22:08.197 D/Mono    (12097): AOT: image 'Mono.Android.Export.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.talkingmedicines.medsmart-353GoKCmCuAZwDW2_PDbJA==/lib/x86/libaot-Mono.Android.Export.dll.so" not found
09-30 15:22:08.199 D/Mono    (12097): AOT: image '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-x86-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/Mono.Android.Export.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.talkingmedicines.medsmart-353GoKCmCuAZwDW2_PDbJA==/lib/x86/libaot-Mono.Android.Export.dll.so" not found
09-30 15:22:08.209 D/Mono    (12097): Config attempting to parse: 'Mono.Android.Export.dll.config'.
09-30 15:22:08.209 D/Mono    (12097): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-x86-release/etc/mono/assemblies/Mono.Android.Export/Mono.Android.Export.config'.
09-30 15:22:08.216 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android.Export[0xc8bfd960] -> mscorlib[0xed8647c0]: 99
Loaded assembly: Mono.Android.Export.dll [External]
09-30 15:22:08.329 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android.Export[0xc8bfd960] -> Mono.Android[0xe63a5c20]: 90
09-30 15:22:08.531 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android.Export[0xc8bfd960] -> System.Xml[0xed845480]: 3
Loaded assembly: __callback_factory__ [External]
09-30 15:22:09.288 D/Mono    (12097): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android.Export[0xc8bfd960] -> System.Core[0xe63a5e00]: 8
09-30 15:22:09.532 D/Mono    (12097): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
09-30 15:22:09.532 D/Mono    (12097): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_new_local_ref'.
09-30 15:22:09.532 D/Mono    (12097): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_new_local_ref'.
09-30 15:22:09.535 D/Mono    (12097): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_new_local_ref'.
Unhandled Exception:

System.AggregateException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>
```

Comment: Please add the stack trace and description of the exception.

Comment: Added, sorry about that

Comment: In the question and not a separate pastebin

Comment: @Cheesebaron, wanted to add a longer trace, but there's a 30k limit on posts that I didn't know about.

Comment: When you get the exception. Please keep pressing continue execution. The exception and stack trace is missing.

Comment: After further investigation, it appears that the error was caused by me changing from PCL libraries to .NetStandard, rather than an issue with MVVMCross itself, Thanks for the help!

Comment: @VaniaP Could you put your comment above in the answer below so that we can close this Question. That way more people facing the same problem will be able to search the solution! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, it appears that the error was caused by me changing from PCL libraries to .NetStandard, rather than an issue with MVVMCross itself, Thanks for the help!